# How to make BeanPropertyRowMapper thread-safe in SpringJdbc?

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, thread-safety, spring-jdbc

I am using spring jdbctemplate in my application and in my query I am using row mapped as new BeanPropertyRowMapper(dto.class)
But I am getting comment from my client to make row mapped thread safe. How it can be done?

The query method looks like:

```
jdbcTemplate.query(qry, new Object[]("abc"), 
    new BeanPropertyRowMapper<dto>(dto.class))
```

Comment: show exactly how you're using it. If you are creating a new instance of the rowmapper within the query method then there should be no possibility for threadsafety issues.

Comment: JdbcTemplate.query(qry, new Object[]("abc"), new BeanPropertyRowMapper<dto>(dto.class)).  Please give explanation  as well

Comment: It's jdbcTemplate sorry for mistake and is injected

Answer (score 2):

Your code is already thread-safe. But you can improve its performance by creating a constant. 
The `BeanPropertyRowMapper` class has mutable data. But once initialized, those data don't change so the class is thread-safe.

Exemple:

```
private static final BeanPropertyRowMapper<dto> DTO_ROW_MAPPER = new dto<dto>(DtoDetailEvenement.class);
...
jdbcTemplate.query(qry, new Object[]("abc"), DTO_ROW_MAPPER)
```

Comment: is BeanPropertyRowMapper thread safe for static usage?

Answer (score 1):

Given this code called from a DAO instance method:

```
jdbcTemplate.query(qry, new Object[]("abc"), new BeanPropertyRowMapper<dto>(dto.class))
```

(where jdbcTemplate is an instance member of the DAO injected by Spring, and the DAO is a Spring-managed bean with singleton scope) then this seems ok. BeanPropertyRowMapper is stateful and would not be threadsafe if used concurrently by multiple threads, but you're not exposing it to multiple threads, you're using it in a thread-confined manner which is safe.

*Java Concurrency in Practice*, section 3.3, discusses thread-confinement in general:

> Accessing shared, mutable data requires using synchronization; one way to avoid this requirement is to not share. If data is only accessed from a single thread, no synchronization is needed. This technique, thread confinement, is one of the simplest ways to achieve thread safety. When an object is confined to a thread, such usage is automatically thread-safe even if the confined object itself is not [CPJ 2.3.2].

It also discusses (in 3.3.2) the particular kind of thread-confinement that you're doing:

> Stack confinement is a special case of thread confinement in which an object can only be reached through local variables. Just as encapsulation can make it easier to preserve invariants, local variables can make it easier to confine objects to a thread. Local variables are intrinsically confined to the executing thread; they exist on the executing thread's stack, which is not accessible to other threads. Stack confinement (also called within-thread or thread-local usage, but not to be confused with the ThreadLocal library class) is simpler to maintain and less fragile than ad-hoc thread confinement.

The only reference to the RowMapper is on the stackframe created for that method call. No other thread (including threads calling the same method on the same DAO) can access it. Tell your client this object is already safe due to being reachable only by local variables, and refer him to the quoted passage from the JCIP book, which is an authoritative reference.

Comment: Under which category my code is falling and is there any changes need to be done to make it thread safe?

Comment: @Vivek: you don't have to do anything, it's safe already. i suspect your client is confused.